# My Jlabel get A value from another class from a JBUtton btn[i] the JLabel shw the value but when i try to get the value from it its shows notthing?

Tags: java, swing

i have 2 classes in java swing in the first one i created JButton btn[]=new JButton[10]; and JButton add[]=new JButton[10]; so if I press add[i] the value of btn[i] is going to be stored in a Jlabel1 in the 2nd class and that jlabel1 will take that value and store it in another Jlabel2 but here when i run the programme i see the value btn[i] in Jlabel 1 but not in Jlabel 2 its like jlabel1 shows its value but when i try to take its value its shows null

here is the code of both classes:

1st class:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JFrame;





public class Testid {



public JButton btn[]=new JButton[10];

public static String testhakou;

public JButton add[] = new JButton[10];

public JFrame jf = null;

int bou=100;

public Testid(){

jf=new JFrame();

jf.setSize(1300,1000);

jf.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

jf.setLayout(null);

for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

btn[i]=new JButton(i+"");

btn[i].setBounds(0,bou,100,30);

jf.add(btn[i]);

bou=bou+50;

}

for(int k=0;k<3;k++){

add[k]=new JButton();

add[k].setText(k+"");

add[k].setBounds(0,bou,100,30);

String b=add[k].getText();

bou=bou+50;

jf.add(add[k]);

add[k].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

u/Override

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

comentaire cm=new comentaire();

testhakou=b;

cm.jLabel1.setText(testhakou);

cm.setVisible(true);

}

} );}

jf.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

new Testid();

}

}
```

---

2nd class:

```
public comentaire() {

initComponents();

jLabel1.setText(publication.testide);

jLabel1.setText(Testid.testhakou);

label1.setText(jLabel1.getText());

}
```

Comment: Please read [How to format posts using Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I tried copying your code into my IDE.  I couldn't get your code to format, much less compile.

Comment: It seems you did not take the advice offered you in the comments to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70549113/getting-the-value-of-a-jbutton-from-a-class-to-another). If you want to get help, I think you need to improve the quality of your questions. Have you taken the [tour]? You get a bronze badge after taking it.

Comment: `Comentaire` is not defined as a class and you're missing an `initComponents` method.  You're using a null layout, which will lead to many more problems.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Comment: Noting you have added a `comentaire` class: Please post a **[mre]**. We should be able to copy/paste the code into an IDE and compile it with no changes, and that is still not possible with the code seen. Tip: Once you *think* you have an MRE, copy/paste it into a new project in the IDE and check it *does* compile with absolutely no alterations. Plus it appears you've still not completed the tour suggested by @Abra. Waste your time if you like, but please don't waste the time of people trying to help (for free).